# Do all published manga originate from one-shots?

Tags: manga-production

I heard that some popular manga (for example - Naruto, Nurarihyon no Mago, Beelzebub) are published as one-shots during their first try. I want to know if that applies to all manga or not? Would many manga be published as a one-shot first?

Comment: I don't know of any comprehensive lists, but it's not surprising that this is a common phenomenon - it allows a publisher to avoid spending excess resources on manga that don't end up succeeding. This doesn't happen for _all_ manga, though (e.g. off the top of my head, I'm pretty sure Gin no Saji [Silver Spoon] didn't start with a one-shot, and there are surely others). Intuitively, it seems that a list of all manga that started with a one-shot would be unmanageably long, so I'm not sure this question is really reasonably scoped.

Comment: No source, but I think all *new* authors have to create one shots. Its part of the path to serialization. As far as I know, the only time a manga starts without a oneshot is if they're already established.

Comment: Asking for a list is too broad as there are probably thousands of manga that would be on the list. In general lots of mangaka (especially new ones) choose to do one-shots to judge how popular something will be and because it's easier to get a publisher to devote resources toward a one-shot than a full series.

Comment: For reference, I did vote to close (as have 2 other people) based on the second question. However, the question in the first sentence, as well as the general question of why manga are often first produced as one-shots, are both fine questions for this site and if the post were edited to that I'd cancel my close vote and/or vote to reopen.

Comment: I don't think this question has to be put on hold. The answer is very specific. Not all manga begin as a oneshot. It is common for mangakas (the authors) to show their editor a few chapters and if the serialization is approved, they get published. Since there are way too many manga to list where it started as a oneshot, just check Myanimelist to see if the series had a oneshot.

Comment: @krikara: If you think the question can be improved and reopened, you may [edit] (or in your case, suggest an edit) to the question, and if it's acceptable, we'll approve and reopen the question.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the request for a list. It should be more appropriate a question now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't apply to all manga. For instance there's manga that are adaptations of other works (anime, video games, light novels) which don't start off as one-shots and have, at the very least, a contractual run. Additionally, there are also manga that are used originally as promotional, as advertisement for a store or an upcoming anime.

The Evangelion manga is an odd-ball, where it was supposed to be an adaptation of the Neon Genesis Evangelion anime series, and start a month or two before its TV run as a promotion for the anime, but the TV run was delayed and didn't actually air until a year's worth of manga chapters. Additionally, there's several recent spin-off manga loosely based on the series.

There's a bunch of Gundam manga that were adapted from anime that were never one-shots. Slayers has several manga series that were adapted from the anime and light novels. Cowboy Bebop, Blade of the Immortal, etc.